# ADC:9:10: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, ros, adc

I'm following this rosserial_arduino tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20Oscilloscope

But when I tried to upload Arduino to library which has this path Arduino IDE>File>Examples>ros_lib>ADC

I got this error:

ADC:9:10: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory

#include <WProgram.h>

```
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

WProgram.h: No such file or directory

I couldn't even change anything so what is the problem?
(I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: it is outdated. WProgram.h is now Arduino.h

Comment: @Juraj I changed it from the code in Arduino Ide but I think I should change this part also from elsewhere because changing only from Ide gives me that error:

Comment: Multiple libraries were found for "ros.h"
 Used: /home/asumansare/Arduino/libraries/ros_lib
 Not used: /home/asumansare/Arduino/libraries/Rosserial_Arduino_Library
sketch_feb28a:3:10: fatal error: rosserial_arduino/Adc.h: No such file or directory
 #include <rosserial_arduino/Adc.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
rosserial_arduino/Adc.h: No such file or directory